# Pyscripter not editable when a sub window is open

Tags: python, pygame, pyscripter

When PyScripter opens another window (eg. a pygame window or matplotlib graphs), I can't edit code until I close the other window. I can move around the code and delete bits, but can't type.

The problem didn't use to occur because the pygame window opened with another program (I think it was python.exe). I don't recall changing anything that would have made this happen; I have always just run a sctipt called Game.py from inside pyscripter which opens the pygame window using pygame.init().

I have python 2.7.9 32bit, pyscripter 2.6.0 32bit (the problem also occured for pyscripter 2.5.3), windows 7 64bit.

How can I either get pygame to open in the python.exe, or change pyscripter so that I can edit scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

Woops I just needed to change run->python engine from internal to remote.